# Fijar tamaño de VideoView

Tags: android

Estoy intentando hacer una app para reproducir vídeos. Estoy usando `VideoView` por defecto. El caso es que intento fijar el tamaño de los vídeos a 1920.

Lo hago de esta forma:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=fullStream.getLayoutParams();
params.width=1920;
fullStream.setLayoutParams(params);
```

El layout

```
    <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/myFullStream"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="0dp"
     />
```

El caso es que cuando el vídeo es de este ancho (1920) o superior se queda en este tamaño, pero cuando el vídeo que intento reproducir es inferior, el `View` se `reescala` al tamaño inferior.

¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Buenas @lois6b resultado no esperado. En el último párrafo explico que el vídeo con un tamaño de ancho inferior a 1920 hace que el videoView cambie su ancho al tamaño del vídeo. Cuando lo que yo quiero es que esté "fijado" a 1920

Comment: entonces si el video es menor es el que tiene que adaptarse al View y no al reves.. entiendo.

Comment: Si, es justo lo que quiero conseguir

Comment: Podrías agregar el layout ?

Comment: @Israel Agregado

Comment: queria ver el layout completo, para ajustarlo y ponerlo en la respuesta, pero para no perder tiempo, coloca el VideoView dentro de un relativelayout y no dentro de un linearlayout